# Multiple cursors in the same for loop

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a question about using cursors.

```
Table t1 having "t1c1" and "t1c2" columns.

Table t2 having "t2c2" and "t2c2" columns.

Table t3 having "t3c2","t3c2","t3c3","t3c4" columns.

Two cursors "cur1" and "cur2".
```

I wrote code where I need to insert values into t3 using for loop of cursor "cur1"

Example:

```
DECLARE

CURSOR cur1 IS
SELECT t1c1 FROM t1;

CURSOR cur2 IS
SELECT t2c1 FROM t2;

BEGIN

FOR f1 IN cur1 LOOP

EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;

INSERT INTO TABLE t3
(
  SELECT f1.t1c1,t2.t2c2,'hello' FROM t2;
);

END LOOP;
```

From the above code I have inserted the 1st three columns of table t3.

I want to know how do I insert cur2 (cursor value) into 4th column of table t3.

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:oracle] and [tag:mysql]: which are you using? Why not use `INSERT ... SELECT` (documentation for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html)) with an appropriate join between your tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t3
select t1.t1c1, t2.t2c2, 'Hello'
from t1,
     t2
```

What is really strange for me you haven't mentioned any links between t1 and t3 so you got cartezian.